# MySQL Calculate the Distance between Zipcodes Faster and More Accurately?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing 42000+ zipcodes, longitude, latitude, and state information.  Whats the most accurate and fastest query to return a result with all zipcodes with a 25 mile radius of the zipcode entered?

Current Code (I don't think its accurate)

```
SELECT
zipcode, (
  3959 * acos (
  cos ( radians(78.3232) )
  * cos( radians( latitude ) )
  * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(65.3234) )
  + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
  * sin( radians( latitude ) )
)
) AS distance
FROM Location
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wouldnt remove the `sql` tag. Because is the generic tag. With this tags, only person looking for `mysql` will look this question

Comment: Slop what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: it doesn't seem accurate to me

Comment: Accurate how? are the distance wrong?

Comment: `78.3232 - 65.3234` is the center zip code, isnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That is rather the point! "Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ANSI SQL.."

Comment: @Strawberry I disagree. If you read sql tooltip  `(SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)` **and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL**. So I think should have both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Accuracy**

The only way to calculate distance accurately is with 3D trig, as you're doing.  You can read more on that topic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Although giving a pretty accurate distance between the lat/lng center-points of zipcodes, **those center-points are arbitrarily picked, and the distance is calculated "as the crow flies"**, so you won't get an accurate representation of actual travel distance between two points within each.

For example, you may have two homes next-door to each other in adjacent zipcodes, or two homes on opposite ends of each zipcode, which will calculate as equidistant given this calculation.

The only way to correct that issue is to calculate address distance, which requires USPS data to map an address to a more specific point, or the use of an API like Google Maps, which will also calculate actual travel distance given available roads.

**On Performance**

There are a couple ways to speed up your query.

**1. Reduce the Real-time Math**

The fastest way to do your calculations in real-time is to precalculate and store the expensive trig values in columns in your table, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE Location
    ADD COLUMN cos_rad_lat DOUBLE,
    ADD COLUMN cos_rad_lng DOUBLE,
    ADD COLUMN sin_rad_lat DOUBLE;
```

Then

```
UPDATE Location
SET cos_rad_lat = cos(radians(latitude)),
    cos_rad_lng = cos(radians(longitude)),
    sin_rad_lat = sin(radians(latitude));
```

Do your cos(radians(78.3232)) type calculations outside the query, so that math isn't done for each row of data.

Thus reducing all calculations to constant values (before getting to SQL) and calculated columns will make your query look like this:

```
SELECT
    zipcode,
    3959 * acos(
        0.20239077538110228
        * cos_rad_lat
        * cos_rad_lng - 1.140108408597264
    )
    + 0.979304842243025 * sin_rad_lat AS distance
FROM Location
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
```

**2. Bounding-box Reduction**

Note: You can combine this with method 1.

You could probably increase performance slightly by adding a bounding-box reduction of zips in a subquery before doing the trig, but that may be more complicated than you would like.

For example, instead of:

```
FROM Location
```

You could do

```
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Location 
    WHERE latitude BETWEEN A and B
        AND longitude BETWEEN C and D
) AS Location
```

Where A, B, C, and D are numbers corresponding to your center-point +- about 0.3 (As each 10th of a degree of lat/lng corresponds to about 5-7 miles in the US).

This method gets tricky at -180 / 180 Longitude, but that doesn't affect the US.

**3. Store All Calculated Distances**
Another thing you could do is precalculate all distances of all zips, and store then in a separate table

```
CREATE TABLE LocationDistance (
    zipcode1 varchar(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES Location(zipcode),
    zipcode2 varchar(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES Location(zipcode)
    distance double NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (zipcode1, zipcode2),
    INDEX (zipcode1, distance)
);
```

Populate this table with every combination of zip and their calculated distance.

Your query would then look like:

```
SELECT zipcode2
FROM LocationDistance 
WHERE zipcode1 = 12345
    AND distance < 25;
```

This would by far be the fastest solution, though it involves storing on the order of 1 Billion records.

Comment: You could do the stored table method on an as needed basis - sort of a chance if you will. Highly unlikely you actually end up using ALL 1 Billion combos :)

Comment: First solution is great, but add `index` for those fields doesn't improve performance. And second solution could be smaller if you only calculate `distance ( zip1, zip2)` where zip1 < zip2. To avoid permutation calculations

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Good point about the indexes, forgot they're being multiplied / added.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already know how to calculate distance using `Latitud, Logitud`

The fastest way is you create the surronding box close to your `ZIPCODE`

```
| X-25, Y-25 |            | X+25, Y-25 |        

                 X , Y

| X-25, Y+25 |            | X+25, Y+25 |
```

So create 4 variables

```
Xleft = X - 25miles
Xright = X + 25miles
Ytop = Y - 25miles
Ybottom = Y + 25miles
```

Then if latitud and longitud have index this query is almost instant

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Location
WHERE 
    latitud between Xleft AND Xright
AND longitud between Ytop AND Ybottom
```

[image]

You will get some error using a square but you will filter most of the wrong zipcodes. Then you could your original query with a much smaller data set.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the fastest, but you can do it by first precomputing the normal vectors (NV) for each coordinate pair and expressing the vector in terms of it's X, Y and Z components:

```
NV = [Nx, Ny, Nz]
```

where

```
Nx = cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude))
Ny = cos(radians(latitude))*sin(radians(longitude))
Nz = sin(radians(latitude))
```

Then the distance between any two coordinates can be computed by determining the difference of the two normal vectors NV1 and NV2 and using Pythagoras equation in three dimensions to get the straight line distance between the two points, that is the chord length C:

```
C = SQRT(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)
```

where

```
dx = Nx1-Nx2
dy = Ny1-Ny2
dz = Nz1-Nz2
```

Then the great circle distance can be found with the following formula:

```
D = arcsin(C/2)*2*R
```

Where R it the radius of the sphere in this case the earth, which is 3959mi.

Putting it all together:

```
 select pt2.zip
      , asin(power(power(pt1.nx-pt2.nx,2)
                  +power(pt1.ny-pt2.ny,2)
                  +power(pt1.nz-pt2.nz,2)
            ,.5)/2)*2*3959 distance
   from (select 78.3232 lattitude
              , 65.3234 longitude
              , cos(radians(78.3232))*cos(radians(65.3234)) nx
              , cos(radians(78.3232))*sin(radians(65.3234)) ny
              , sin(radians(78.3232)) nz
        ) pt1
      , (select zip
              , lattitude
              , longitude
              , cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)) nx
              , cos(radians(latitude))*sin(radians(longitude)) ny
              , sin(radians(latitude)) nz
           from location) pt2
having distance < 25;
```

To further optimize this you can calculate a some bounds on the coordinates.  Every degree of latitude is roughly equal to 69 miles so you can limit your search to those latitudes ±(D/69).  The number of miles per degree of longitude, however, varies with the latitude ranging from about 69 miles per degree at the equator to zero at the poles or 69*cos(latitude), you use ±(D/69*cos(latitude)).

```
 where pt2.latitude  between pt1.latitude - 25/69
                         and pt1.latitude + 25/69
   and pt2.longitude between pt1.longitude - 25/(69*cos(radians(abs(pt1.latitude)+25/69)))
                         and pt1.longitude + 25/(69*cos(radians(abs(pt1.latitude)+25/69)))
```